# Is the Java version vulnerable to leap seconds?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat7

I want to know if the Java build 1.7.0_51-b13 version is vulnerable to leap seconds or not?

I have a cluster of servers running Tomcat. Since July 1 we have a huge CPU usage. We tried to stop ntp and `date -s "date"` in vain.

The Redhat kernel and tzdata package were patched since June.

useful links:

- https://ma.ttias.be/a-fix-for-the-java-leap-second-bug/
- https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/the_2015_leap_second_s

Comment: What do you mean by "vulnerable to leap seconds?"  The most likely answer is "maybe for a second."  Or perhaps you're talking about time accuracy?

Comment: vulnerable in this case mean ==> CPU overload usage and system instability

Comment: The likelihood that an extra second in a time calculation is going to overload your CPU is pretty much zero.  There's an infinitesimally small chance of some sort of crash or exception, but it's so unlikely as to be not worth worrying about.

Comment: @RobertHarvey have a look on the links that i've added on my post

Comment: Had a similar issue; we have a number of (virtual) Debian servers. Huge CPU usage after the night with the leap second but it looked like it was not because of our Java processes. Rebooted the servers and problem went away.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Software can do strange things when an extra second is added to the clock; it's not so surprising that some pieces of software can't deal with a leap second properly.

Comment: @Jesper: Unfortunately the answer to the question "Is a leap second bug in the Java JDK causing our huge CPU usage issues?" is "We don't know."

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's true, we don't know. But your comments seemed to suggest to me that you didn't believe there's any chance that this might cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's down to the implementation. It's unlikely that your JVM supports leap seconds.

From `java.util.Date` documentation:

> Although the Date class is intended to reflect coordinated universal
>   time (UTC), it may not do so exactly, depending on the host
>   environment of the Java Virtual Machine. Nearly all modern operating
>   systems assume that 1 day = 24 × 60 × 60 = 86400 seconds in all cases.
>   In UTC, however, about once every year or two there is an extra
>   second, called a "leap second." The leap second is always added as the
>   last second of the day, and always on December 31 or June 30. For
>   example, the last minute of the year 1995 was 61 seconds long, thanks
>   to an added leap second. Most computer clocks are not accurate enough
>   to be able to reflect the leap-second distinction.

(Out of interest, and not connected at all with Java, Google NTP servers stretch the seconds in a day that has a leap second, so the extra time is allocated linearly across the seconds in that day.)

Comment: `Google stretch the seconds in a day that has a leap second, so the extra time is allocated linearly across the seconds in that day` -- Really?  I very much doubt that.  Every implementation on the planet adds an extra second in the minute just before midnight.

Comment: google smears the leap second in their NTP infrastructure, which doesn't have anything to do with java.

Comment: @MarcB Indeed: that was what I was trying to say.

Comment: That would be damned inconvenient for any application that expects individual seconds to be an accurate time referent.

Comment: Yup. That's life. If you need accurate timings then you're best off writing your own stuff or using a rigid library designed for that purpose. (I worked with such things during my doctorate.)

Comment: The new java.time framework also defines a Leap Second Smear over the last thousand seconds of the day (same idea as Google's smear but different details). See [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30989049/642706) on similar Question for doc excerpts. But this smear is only required where the Java implementation *has* a leap second. No conventional Java implementation I know of recognizes the Leap Second (perhaps a Real-Time Java implementation might). So effectively, all three Java date-time frameworks (java.util.Date/.Calendar, Joda-Time, java.time) ignore Leap Second.