# How to get hour form Date in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, date, kotlin, deprecated

I try to get hour from Date data type in Kotlin but get this error:

> 'getter for hours: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

And my code:

```
val date:Date = ...
val hour = date.hours
```

this is deprecated and  `getHours()`  not found ...

Comment: I think you are looking for `getHours()`. That's what [oficial documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-date/index.html) says

Comment: I suggest that it’s a near-duplicate of [Fastest way to get hour of java.util.date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200459/fastest-way-to-get-hour-of-java-util-date) You may search for more similar questions.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That entire class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use an appropriate class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: getMinutes and getHours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907170/java-getminutes-and-gethours)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`getHours()` is deprecated. It replaced by  `Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`

```
val date:Date = ... // your date
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.time = date
val hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
```