# How to compare a leapsecond with java.time and Junit?

Tags: java, time, junit, leap-second

So I have a LocalDateTime parser which accepts a date as a String.
I have wrote several tests for it e.g. checking for leap year and some more.

Now I want a JUnit test to check for a leap second.
I did some research and found that probably it is not possible with java.time(?).
So far I found a suitable date on which a leap second occured.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Check for leap second")
void shouldLeapSecondOccurReturnExactlyTwoMinuteSpan() {
    String leapSecond = "2015-06-30T23:59:00+0000";
    String leapSecond2 = "2015-07-01T00:01:00";
    Assertions.assertTrue(DateConvertUtils.parseIso8601ToUTC(leapSecond)
   .isEqual(LocalDateTime.parse(leapSecond2).minusSeconds(120)));
}
```

While `DateConvertUtils` contains my above mentioned parser and a custom `DateTimeFormatter`.

I appreciate any help to the right direction.

Comment: What is `DateConvertUtils`...?

Comment: As far as I know, `java.time` will ignore leapseconds, see [How does the (Oracle) Java JVM know a leap second is occurring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984599/how-does-the-oracle-java-jvm-know-a-leap-second-is-occurring) (see the answer by Basil Bourque).

Comment: As far as I know, the only leap second support in java.time is that for an `Instant` a leap seoncd can be parsed. For example `Instant.parse("2015-06-30T23:59:60Z")` works (but yeilds `2015-06-30T23:59:59Z` because `Instant` cannot *hold* a leap second).

Answer (score 1):

Well, leap seconds are ignored by most libraries including `java.time`-package. My lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) however, supports it. Example using your input:

```
    String s1 = "2015-06-30T23:59:00+0000";
    String s2 = "2015-07-01T00:01:00"; // no offset information

    ChronoFormatter<Moment> f =
        ChronoFormatter
            .ofMomentPattern(
                "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[X]", // optional offset
                PatternType.CLDR, 
                Locale.ROOT, 
                ZonalOffset.UTC); // default offset

    Moment m1 = f.parse(s1);
    Moment m2 = f.parse(s2); // no offset => UTC

    long delta = SI.SECONDS.between(m1, m2);
    System.out.println(delta); // 121
```

Objects of type [Moment](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/Moment.html) can be easily converted to/from `java.time.Instant` if you are willing to loose the possible leap second information (in case you have `2015-06-30T23:60Z`).

**Good to know:** You really need at least a class connected to UTC timeline. Classes like `LocalDateTime` have no concept of time zones so they have no connection to UTC and are unusable for determining leap seconds by definition.

More background information can be found in my [DZone paper](https://dzone.com/articles/how-watch-next-coming-leap).