# Why does the difference between 30 March and 1 March 2020 erroneously give 28 days instead of 29?

Tags: java, date, java-7, datediff

```
TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(
   Math.abs(
      new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("30-03-2020 00:00:00").getTime() - 
      new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("1-03-2020 00:00:00").getTime()
   ),
   TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

The result is 28, while it should be 29.

Could the time zone/location be the problem?

Comment: Note: Please don't use `SimpleDateFormat` any longer, for it's obsolete. Use packages from `java.time` instead. In `SimpleDateFormat`'s case, use `DateTimeFormatter`. In case of Java 7, see Andy Turner's comment below.

Comment: *Don't* do maths on times. Use a proper time library (`java.time` [although I note you are on Java 7], [ThreeTenBp](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp), Joda).

Comment: I would love to have been in the meeting where someone goes "Okay, now that we've got timezones kinda figured out let's go 100% arse-mode and implement this thing called daylight savings which came to me in a dream after my acid trip last night."

Comment: @Andreas I wonder how does TimeUnit (pretends to) know when is DST shift in any given Time Zone, since it's not a fixed date and can even change from one year to the another.

Comment: @gmauch [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) doesn't pretend to know anything about DST. As the javadoc says: *A nanosecond is defined as one thousandth of a microsecond, a microsecond as one thousandth of a millisecond, a millisecond as one thousandth of a second, a minute as sixty seconds, an hour as sixty minutes, and **a day as twenty four hours**.* --- Since DST causes 2 days of the year to not be exactly 24 hours, `TimeUnit` gets it wrong when DST is involved.

Comment: This problem occurs only on computers that are in time zones with daylight savings.

It gives the correct number of days (29) in time zones that do not have daylight savings!

Comment: Every possible question about programming with time or dates that was ever or will ever be asked was already answered by Tom Scott: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm guessing that meeting was held in the summer, when they realized they'd rather enjoy that hour of daylight at the end of the day than waste it at the beginning of the day while they were at work.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

The problem is that because of Daylight Saving Time shift (on Sunday, March 8, 2020), there are **28 days and 23 hours** between those dates. `TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(...)` *truncates* the result to 28 days.

To see the problem (I'm in US Eastern time zone):

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
long diff = fmt.parse("30-03-2020 00:00:00").getTime() -
            fmt.parse("1-03-2020 00:00:00").getTime();

System.out.println(diff);
System.out.println("Days: " + TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(Math.abs(diff), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
System.out.println("Hours: " + TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(Math.abs(diff), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
System.out.println("Days: " + TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(Math.abs(diff), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) / 24.0);
```

*Output*

```
2502000000
Days: 28
Hours: 695
Days: 28.958333333333332
```

To fix, use a time zone that doesn't have DST, e.g. **UTC**:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
long diff = fmt.parse("30-03-2020 00:00:00").getTime() -
            fmt.parse("1-03-2020 00:00:00").getTime();
```

*Output*

```
2505600000
Days: 29
Hours: 696
Days: 29.0
```

Comment: "To fix" don't do maths with times. Use a proper date/time library.

Comment: @AndyTurner To fix, using built-in Java 7 APIs. Since it *can* be fixed, showing how is a valid answer. Forcing someone to include a full library (Joda-Time, ThreeTen, etc.) just to do this one calculation would be overkill. Sure, using a library would be recommended, but is not *required*.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. If you want to do a calculation, do it right; pay the cost to do it right.

Comment: My € 0.02: The “right” way to do in Java 7 without any external library would be to use a `GregorianCalendar` object and add 1 day at a time until the end date is reached. I’d pay a high price to avoid that. And adding the backport of a library that is already part of Java 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, … is no high price. On the contrary, next time you need to do anything with date or time, it will already be a gain.

Comment: Even in UTC the last day of June is occasionally one second too short, without any real warning or predictability.  Always use a date-time library.

Comment: @Affe None of the Java time APIs handle second adjustments, so that is not an issue. They all define that there are exactly 86400 seconds per day. See e.g. [How does the (Oracle) Java JVM know a leap second is occurring?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30989049/5221149).

Comment: @Affe : Although negative [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) are potentially allowed, none have ever been applied.  To date, leap seconds have been inserted in the last second of June and the last second of December, making the last days of those months one second "too" *long*.  I recall that there is provision for an additional pair of potential insertions in the last day of each of March and September, but I don't recall where I read this.

Comment: @EricTowers The code in the question and in this answer is working with milliseconds-since-epoch. It is **impossible** for a `millis` value to represent leap seconds, positive or negative, by the very *nature* of the value, so the discussion about leap seconds is *irrelevant* to this answer.

Comment: @Andreas : Take it up with Affe; I didn't introduce the topic.  I merely corrected a sign and month error in his comment.

Comment: I'm sure the answer correctly solves the specific problem that was asked for this combination of question, language, and runtime.  I certainly did not downvote it.  I am aware JSR-310 "solved" the problem I brought up for supported versions of java by literally *creating a new java-specific definition of what "one second" even means*.  I will cite the fact they felt the need to do that as compelling evidence to avoid the rabbit hole of mixing "human" date time with "machine" date time :)

Comment: Library bloat was a rookie concern even before there were tree shaking tools like ProGuard. Bloat is the price we pay for rapid development and ease of maintenance.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Actually, I would argue there's more here: whether this calculation is "right" or not depends on what semantics you are after. If the semantics is that it should be the _physical time interval_ between the two points which, mind you, are specified down _to the second_, then the correct answer really _is_ 28 days and 23 hours when it is taken as being in that time zone, rounded however you prefer.

Comment: But if the desired semantics is "how many squares on the calendar are the dates [not date/times] away from each other", then yes, it should be 29, and this calculating method is wrong for that purpose.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, um, I don't think using 12 o'clock here helps? The time interval between the two noons will still be 28 days and 23 hours, which still truncates to 28. You could use noon on the other end, and midnight on the other, of course, but then I think you might as well round the difference instead of truncating it.

Comment: @Eric, I'm sure that Affe is aware that Java pretends there are always 86400 seconds in the day: that's why it sometimes shows that 30th June or 31st December as one second too short (specifically, when the day has 86401 seconds, but Java ignores 23:59:60).

Comment: Where is Jon Skeet when you need him? ;-)

Answer (score 41):

The cause of this problem is already mentioned in [Andreas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60071551/507738).

The question is *what* exactly you want to count. The fact that you state that the actual difference should be 29 instead of 28, and ask whether *"location/zone time could be a problem"*, reveals what you actually want to count. Apparently, you want to get rid of any timezone difference.

I assume you only want to calculate the days, without time and timezone.

#### Java 8

Below, in the example of how the number of days between could be calculated correctly, I'm using a class that represents exactly that – a date without time and timezone – `LocalDate`.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse("1-03-2020 00:00:00", formatter);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse("30-03-2020 00:00:00", formatter);

long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);
```

---

Note that `ChronoUnit`, `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDate` require at least Java 8, which is not available to you, according to the [java-7](/questions/tagged/java-7) tag. However, it perhaps is to future readers.

As mentioned by Ole V.V., there's also the [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/), which backports Java 8 Date and Time API functionality to Java 6 and 7.

Comment: @OleV.V. I know there is ThreeTen, some users may have mentioned it a few times. (I was about to link to a SEDE query returning all posts and comments of user 5772882 containing the text `ThreeTen` ;-), but unfortunately it is offline at the time of writing.) I will update the post.

Comment: @OleVV It's not a bad thing at all. I think most people are simply ignorant about `java.time`, because at school they still use the old classes. But the Java 8 Date and Time API is very well designed – it would be a loss *not* to use it.