How do you assess code for problems handling leap seconds (particularly Java)?
We recently got notice that there may be a negative leap second at the end of the year and we need to determine how it will affect our programs (we write mostly Java programs). I've done some searching on this site and around the web and I see some discussions about leap seconds, but they all seem to be about "does this block of code have a problem with leap seconds?" or "how does Java handle leap seconds?" And even then, the answers are hard to wrap my mind around. It's hard to figure out what it means for time to change out from under you.
So are there any general ways to say "if you use this utility class to do X" or "if you're reading or displaying times like this", that it would cause a problem when there is a positive or negative leap second? Our java apps do things like: use ScheduledExecutorService to do repeating tasks or check if too much time has passed between two events (generally at least 30 seconds), read files that have event datetimes in them, and display those times. One of the apps displays a schedule of events and the display changes when events start or stop (yes, this old app is still in Swing).
We also have a Vue app for displaying these same things and a C++ library for creating a common interface to different message buses, but I'd be fine with making separate questions for those if needed.
Edit:
This post was labeled a duplicate of How does the (Oracle) Java JVM know a leap second is occurring? but I don't see how it's a duplicate. That question asks how java knows a leap second is occurring, regarding a very specific operation, whereas my question is about what kinds of operations have problems caused by leap seconds.

This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984599/how-does-the-oracle-java-jvm-know-a-leap-second-is-occurring

The short of it: You can safely ignore this; java takes care of leap seconds inherently. See the linked answer for more details.

What negative leap second? That has never happened afaik, though the authorities reserve the right to do so. And I have not heard of one this year. Please cite a reference. The latest I see is the U.S. Naval Observatory saying no Leap Second of any kind is scheduled for 2024.

@BasilBourque That notice was posted July 4, 2024. We got our instructions to look into this before that, when they were still considering a negative leap second.

@cymbalblade I would appreciate if you could link to that notice, to satisfy my curiosity.

The only official thing I have is the notice from July 4, 2024 that there will not be a leap second.
https://datacenter.iers.org/data/html/bulletinc-068.html
Besides that I just have an email from my organization saying to look into handling leap seconds.

If you look at the pattern of leap second occurrences over the years, it does seem as if the earth's rotation is slowing (due to global warming some say), so a negative leap second is possible.  But, on 18 November 2022, the General Conference on Weights and Measures (CGPM) resolved to eliminate leap seconds by or before 2035. The difference between atomic and astronomical time will be allowed to grow to a larger value yet to be determined.  Then again, there are folks trying to stop this.  So it is unclear if a negative leap second will ever happen.

For the most part leap seconds are irrelevant to programming, as time is generally recorded as the number of milliseconds past an epoch (Jan 1, 1970 I believe) in a given timezone (I believe GMT/UTC is used)
Leap years and leap seconds only affect how the aforementioned number is displayed in terms of date notation that we typically use (i.e. Month, Day, Year, time zone) which can be translated from the numeric format. Leap years and leap seconds are necessary because Earth's full rotation around the sun takes approximately 365 1/4 days so to keep the seasons stable we need this, and also that computers measure time more accurately than how the earth actually rotates, so leap seconds are necessary to keep 12:00 PM as high noon.
For more, you can read here: https://www.epochconvert.com/

The main point is that, when Java converts from epoch seconds to year/month/day/hours/minutes/seconds, it treats every single minute as having exactly 60 seconds, despite the fact that's not actually the case in the real world.

@k314159 Re: length of a second - What you claim is correct ONLY because we define 1 second so precisely. The conflict is that days and years also have precise definitions, and that 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour, 24 hours in a day, and 365 days in a year varies from how the Earth rotates and travels around the Sun - both astrological events have more variance. So something's got to give.

The whole time thing is too complex. There are several different definitions, including Universal Time, largely based on astronomical motions, and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), based on atomic clocks. And I can never remember what is the exact difference between UTC and GMT, I just know there is some obscure distinction. Also I have difficulty remembering whether 12 pm is noon or midnight ("pm" = post meridiem, meaning "after noon", but noon 12 pm is neither before or after noon, it's noon.) Perhaps we should split the day into 1000 millidays, then there would be no confusion ;-)

@k314159 re: The whole time thing is too complex- And then there are the effects of gravity on time (a la Einstein and relativity) it truly is too complex.

Indeed, I had forgotten that. But I've heard that relativity is taken into account for GPS satellites which are travelling quite fast.

Actually this issue is not so complicated from a practical point of view. The whole point of Leap Second(s) is to adjust our calendar system of years and months (Earth going around the Sun) with our clock (hours-minutes-seconds). We stop the clock for a second to match the calendar. So a Leap Second by design is meant to be “absorbed” into the calendar, Leap Second is meant to be ignored. So the Java Time-Scale is properly designed for general-purpose business apps.

Ignoring Leap Second is the smart thing to do for general-purpose computing and for usual business apps. If you really need to track Leap Second for some unusual/extreme reason, consider the ThreeTen-Extra library with its alternate time-scales. Its UtcInstant class includes Leap Seconds.

I don't agree that leap seconds have anything to do with the calendar (months & years) or with the Earth's orbit around the Sun. It is only connected to the Earth's rotation (around its own axis). Leap seconds are used because of slight variations in the speed at which the Earth rotates. Even if we didn't have the concept of a year, and followed a calendar that was just N number of days (such as Julian Day), we would still need to introduce leap seconds every now and then.
